# How to prevent close popup on map move?

Tags: leaflet, popup

Leaflet 1.7.1
Moving map close popups. If the map keeps moving after the GPS, it's quite inconvenient.

Is there a way to prevent closing popup on map move?

{autoClose:false} does not help

Comment: The popup in the demo at the main https://leafletjs.com/ webpage doesn't close when moving the map around. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As a @IvanSanchez say, the popup doesn't close when moving the map around. In my case, the object was destroyed and created again.
Correcting this behavior solved the problem.